# Azure - FetchAttributes vs. Table Storage for Image Metadata

Tags: c#, azure

I have several thousand images of famous artworks stored in Azure Container Storage. Each image has some artwork information associated with it e.g. Title, Artist, Year etc. Currently this information is stored in Azure Table storage where I do a retrieval based on the image ID. However, would it be better (in terms of performance and best-practice) to store this information as attribute data for the image and then call?:

```
var myAttributes = myBlockBlob.FetchAttributesAsync();
```

Here is the current way I do it, using Azure Table Retrieve:

```
var myGetOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<TileInfoEntity>("0", imageID);
var myResult = await myTable.ExecuteAsync(myGetOperation);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There's not necessarily a right or wrong way to deal with content metadata - you can store it anywhere you want.

Just keep in mind: blob storage doesn't provide query tools for metadata, so there's no straightforward way to work with metadata aside from direct-read of a specific blob's metadata.

Storage systems like Table Storage allow for queries based on partition and/or row key, providing different data types, providing CRUD operations, etc. Same with any other database engine, as they all provide some type of indexing/query support.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing faster than retrieving from Table Storage knowing **row key + partition key** would be to warm up a [Redis Cache](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cache-dotnet-how-to-use-azure-redis-cache) with all the metadata and pull from that.

```cs
cache.StringSet("key1", "value1");
string value = cache.StringGet("key1");
```

To be honest i don't think the performance gain will be significant if we're not talking at least 1k requests/second.

[IIS kernel-mode output cache](http://www.drupalonwindows.com/en/blog/getting-2000-requests-second-without-varnish) is also a good candidate if your requests are well-formed (i.e. look like a static object).

```xml
<system.webServer>
    <caching>
        <profiles>
            <add extension=".metadata" policy="CacheForTimePeriod"
             duration="00:00:55" varyByHeaders="Accept-Language" />
        </profiles>
    </caching>                  
</system.webServer>
```

Know where your bottleneck is - don't optimize stuff your telemetry doesn't point fingers at.